# DHTMLX grid header tool tip

Tags: grid, dhtmlx

How can i add tool tip for DHTMLX grid suppose i am having 1st column named MOP, which stands for **Mode of payment** how do i enable tool tip for this header on hover MOP it should display Mode of payment.

How do i achieve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the solution proposed at: http://forum.dhtmlx.com/viewtopic.php?f=14&t=11808 .

Answer (score 0):

To enable/disable tooltips for specified columns in dhtmlx grid,
this function is used:

**void enableTooltips(string list);**

Example:

```
//disable first column's tooltips
myGrid.enableTooltips("false,true,true,true,true");
```

For more details please visit https://docs.dhtmlx.com/api__dhtmlxgrid_enabletooltips.html.

Comment: Wrong answer. This tooltips only for data, not for header. You can check here: https://dhtmlx.com/docs/products/dhtmlxGrid/samples/16_rows_columns_manipulations/04_grid_tooltip.html